# writeToFile method not working for ipod

Tags: iphone, excel, ipod

In my app we retrieve data from database using sqlite and write the whole data to a file of type xls ie excel sheet. For iPhone its working fine, we get the excel sheet. But when the same app is run on iPod we are not getting the excel sheet.

I have used:
 https://github.com/andreac/RSSheet for writing data to excel sheet.

Is there another way to write to file for iPod or writing to file using application document directory works fine for iPod?

Thanks.

Comment: An iPod Touch should be same as an iPhone, only you don't have any GSM/GPS functions. Could the iOS version be the problem?